# e's Datasource Not injecting in @controller in spring-mvc 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am trying to develop a spring-mvc 3 web application for the learning purpose.
as a newbie i'am not very good in spring mvc.

so here is the problem my datasource of AdminDAO.java always returns null in @controller class

```
@Controller
public class adminPanel {

    @Autowired
    IAdminServices adminDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value={"/adminPanel.spring"},method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String execute(@ModelAttribute Login login){
        return "adminpanel";
....
    }
```

here datasource always injected with null

her is my application context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="datasource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/librarysystem" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
    </bean>

<bean id="adminDAO" class="in.kailash.DAO.AdminDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

my IAdminServices.java

```
@Component
public interface IAdminServices {
    public String save(User user);
    public String delete(User user,String id);
    public String edit(User user,String id);
    public List<User> viewAll();
    public String issue();
    public String returnBook();
    public String getStudentCardNumber();
}
```

AdminDAO class implementing IAdminServices.java

```
@Service
public class AdminDAO implements IAdminServices {

    DataSource dataSource;

    public AdminDAO() {
        super();
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public String save(User user) {
         try {
            Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
            String sql = "insert into borrower(cardno,name,address,phone)   VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
...
....
}
```

Here's my mvc-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="in.kailash" />

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

here's my web.xml

```
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns      /javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LibSys</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>maincontroller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>maincontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.spring</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/maincontroller-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

my main problem is that i always get datasource as null in @controller class.
as i am a newbie so any further comments about how to arrange classes in Spring-mvc is welcomed.

thanks in advance.

---

@Sotirios Thanks for your patience reply. according to your suggestions i have done changes in my

> web.xml

as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>LibSys</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>maincontroller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/maincontroller-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>maincontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.spring</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationcontext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Somehow datasource is now getting injected. I only want to confirm that this time i have done this right. and if you find any problem in my package arrangement then please comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your `AdminDAO` class is nested somewhere inside the package declared here

```
<context:component-scan base-package="in.kailash" />
```

If that's the case, Spring will generate a new bean for the type `AdminDAO` since it is annotated with `@Service`. It will process this bean, but won't autowire the `DataSource` in it because you haven't asked it to. This `AdminDAO` bean is then injected into your `@Controller`, not the one from the application context.

Instead, it seems you want to use the `AdminDAO` bean you've declared in your application context.

You have 2 options:

- Remove the `@Service` annotation from the `AdminDAO` class so that Spring correctly uses the `AdminDAO` `<bean>` you've declared in the application context.
- Remove the `<bean>` declaration for `AdminDAO` and add `@Autowired` to the `DataSource` field or setter

Comment: Dear thanks for your reply my AdminDAO is inside in.kailash.DAO package and after removing the @services from my AdminDAO it throughs exception
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminPanel': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: in.kailash.services.IAdminServices in.kailash.controller.adminPanel.adminDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [in.kailash.services.IAdminServices]

Comment: @R's Can you edit your question and add your web.xml? Where do you declare your application context?

Comment: @R's Ok, so now something doesn't make sense. Was `mvc-servlet.xml` meant to be `maincontroller-servlet.xml`? In any case, your `DispatcherServlet` should load the `mvc-servlet.xml` (or wtv) and the `ContextLoaderListener` should load the application context.

Comment: @Sotirious yes mvc-servlet means maincontroller-servlet.xml. but rest of the things you said is not understable ..and i also have contextconfig entry in web.xml

Comment: @R's Currently, both your `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` are loading the same `maincontroller-servlet.xml`. You're loading it twice and it doesn't contain the dao bean. Have your `DispatcherServlet` load the `maincontroller-servlet.xml` and have your `ContextLoaderListener` load the application context file, whatever it is called.